# Order by total count in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tabel structure as follow

[image]

Now my requirement is i need vendor who's deals are downloaded most for that i have query

```
SELECT vendor_id,COUNT(deal_id) AS total_dealid 
FROM `user_downloaded_deals` 
GROUP BY `vendor_id`
```

But it returns data by vendor_id order i need data by `total_dealid` ORder. means the deal of vendor whos downloaded most is shows first
For example current o/p is

```
vendor_id   total_dealid
1           3
2           2
5           5
```

Expected O/p

```
vendor_id   total_dealid
5           5
1           3
2           2
```

Comment: Simply add an `ORDER BY COUNT(deal_id)`?

Comment: `SELECT vendor_id,COUNT(deal_id) AS total_dealid FROM `user_downloaded_deals` GROUP BY `vendor_id` ORDER BY COUNT(deal_id)`

Comment: I have tried by `ORDER BY total_dealid ` Which is not working

Comment: Check @Lovepreet Singh Answer

Comment: Thanks all for answer

Answer (score 1):

try this query

```
SELECT vendor_id,COUNT(deal_id) AS total_dealid 
FROM `user_downloaded_deals` 
GROUP BY `vendor_id` ORDER BY total_dealid DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this query

```
SELECT vendor_id,COUNT(deal_id) AS total_dealid FROM user_downloaded_deals 
 GROUP BY vendor_id order by total_dealid desc
```

[image]

Without "order by"
[image]

Comment: dont need `sum` need `count`

Comment: ah sorry i am not understand. try this query: SELECT vendor_id,COUNT(deal_id) AS total_dealid 
FROM `user_downloaded_deals` 
GROUP BY `vendor_id` order by total_dealid desc

Answer (score 0):

**order by** can be used with alias also so query will be as follows:

```
SELECT vendor_id, COUNT(deal_id) AS total_dealid FROM `user_downloaded_deals` 
    GROUP BY `vendor_id` ORDER BY total_dealid DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't order by `total_dealid`. In SQL it's not possible to sort by an aliased column. Instead, you have to repeat your order statement. The following should solve your issue.

```
SELECT vendor_id,COUNT(deal_id) AS total_dealid 
FROM `user_downloaded_deals` 
GROUP BY `vendor_id`
ORDER BY count(deal_id) DESC;
```

EDIT: Newer SQL versions allows order by an aliased colum, so this should also work:

```
SELECT vendor_id,COUNT(deal_id) AS total_dealid 
FROM `user_downloaded_deals` 
GROUP BY `vendor_id`
ORDER BY total_dealid DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add order by total_dealid  or count(deal_id) desc

```
SELECT vendor_id,COUNT(deal_id) AS total_dealid 
FROM `user_downloaded_deals` 
GROUP BY `vendor_id` order by total_dealid  Desc
```